# Jackson read value as string

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an object with unknown values, say

```
{
 "data": [
    {"a":...,
    "dont_know_what_else_is_here":....}
 ]
}
```

And I just want to store the value of "data" as a string into a variable/database.

How should I read it from the streaming API?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Provided that you have already read this object into `JsonNode`, you can do it like this:

```
String content = jsonNode.get("data").textValue();
```

UPD: since you're using a streaming parser, [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example) example on Jackson usage might help.

UPD: the method name is now textValue() - [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#textValue())

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is from a streaming parser, so unfortunately it is not read into a jsonNode yet. If I can read it to json node then toString the whole object will work.

Comment: @Edison Oh, I see now. Have you checked out [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example) example?

Comment: Yea I did, but I have unknown structure inside the data array. any ideas?

Comment: edited the question as well. the data is an array with mixed objects.

Comment: Read that page again and found the answer at the bottom of that page.

Comment: @Edison Good to hear this =) I've edited my answer as well to include link to API usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not getTextValue() but simply textValue()

Comment: @AnatoliiStepaniuk You can add this as edit. I suppose, this is API change in newer version.

Comment: depending on the version, you can also see .asText();

Comment: @joeybaruch asText() will convert any non text into string value while textValue() for if you're certain it is a string.

Comment: `NullPointerException` will occur if `data` isn't available in the `JsonNode`

Answer (score 36):

When we try to fetch data in form of string from JsonNode,we usually use **asText**, but we should use **textValue** instead.
[**asText**](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asText()): Method that will return a valid String representation of the container value, if the node is a value node (method isValueNode() returns true), otherwise empty String.
[**textValue**](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#textValue()): Method to use for accessing String values. Does NOT do any conversions for non-String value nodes; for non-String values (ones for which isTextual() returns false) null will be returned. For String values, null is never returned (but empty Strings may be)

So Let's take an example,

```
JsonNode getJsonData(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode(); 
    node.put("anyParameter",null);
    return node;
}
JsonNode node = getJsonData();
json.get("anyParameter").asText() // this will give output as "null"
json.get("").textValue() // this will give output as null
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the data in a map according to key value pairs.

```
Map<String, Object> mp = mapper.readValue(new File("xyz.txt"),new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

Now get the value from map:

```
mp.get("data");
```

Comment: I am using a streaming parser so I don't want to read "data" as a whole.

Comment: @dejavu hi, what is the best way to get the sting from a URL with mapper?

Comment: how do I convert jsonNode to string[] in java?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you've got a **parser** already and it points to *"data"* token (e.g. from custom deserializer) you can do the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode treeNode = mapper.readTree(parser);
return treeNode.toString();
```

This will get you String containing the value of the *"data"*.

Answer (score 4):

You can have some Entity class for JSON result.

```
String json = "your_json";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Entity entity = mapper .readValue(json, Entity.class);
// here you can do everything with entity as you wish

// to write Entity value as String when you wish
String text = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
// to write Entity child's value as String when you wish (let's data contain data part)
String data = mapper.writeValueAsString(object.getData());
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a POJO java class called User([Taken from this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes))

```
public class User {
public enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE };

public class Name {
    private String _first, _last;

    public String getFirst() { return _first; }
    public String getLast() { return _last; }

    public void setFirst(String s) { _first = s; }
    public void setLast(String s) { _last = s; }
}

private Gender _gender;
private Name _name;
private boolean _isVerified;
private byte[] _userImage;

public Name getName() { return _name; }
public boolean isVerified() { return _isVerified; }
public Gender getGender() { return _gender; }
public byte[] getUserImage() { return _userImage; }

public void setName(Name n) { _name = n; }
public void setVerified(boolean b) { _isVerified = b; }
public void setGender(Gender g) { _gender = g; }
public void setUserImage(byte[] b) { _userImage = b; }
```

}

So now you have JSON string which is coming from any place somewhere like web socket or somewhere else.As an example assume this is the string you are getting

```
String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"name\" : { \"first\" : \"Joe\", \"last\" : \"Sixpack\" },\n" +
            "  \"gender\" : \"MALE\",\n" +
            "  \"verified\" : false,\n" +
            "  \"userImage\" : \"Rm9vYmFyIQ==\"\n" +
            "}";
```

Now you can convert this JSON string into POJO object just using this piece of code.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper .readValue(json, User.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the solution from reading the tutorial page.

Just to give others a pointer here:

1. Switch to using a MappingJSONFactory when creating the parser:

   ```
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
       JsonFactory jfactory = new MappingJsonFactory();
       JsonParser parser=jfactory.createJsonParser(response.getEntity().getContent());
   ```
2. Then you can just do

   ```
       parser.readValueAsTree().toString();
   ```

or parse it however you want.

Comment: Last I checked, some of the toString methods were just for debugging and were not guaranteed to produce valid JSON representative of their contents.

Comment: Good to know. It worked for me on a very complex object. Time to double check though...

Comment: fortunately "org.codehaus.jackson.map.MappingJsonFactory" does implement toString properly. :) @ProgrammerBruce

Comment: For now.  But I didn't see in the JavaDocs where it was guaranteed to keep working in future releases.

Comment: @ProgrammerBruce you are right, `JsonNode.toString()` is not the right way to do conversion -- rather, `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(node)` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to read a sub-tree from input using Streaming API -- but in the end, you need to whole sub-tree as one thing to store in DB (or variable).

So what you probably want to use is `JsonParser.readValueAs(MyType.class)` -- this will call `ObjectMapper` (and for it to work, parser has to be created via `JsonFactory` accessed from `ObjectMapper`; or you need to call `JsonFactory.setCodec(mapper)`).

If content is arbitrary, you can read it as `Map` or `JsonNode`:

```
Map<String,Object> map = parser.readValueAs(Map.class);
// or
JsonNode root = parser.readValueAsTree();
```

as soon as `JsonParser` is pointing to START_ELEMENT of the JSON Object you want to databind.

Answer (score 0):

If using `String data` in `createParser(data)`, i use this method to collect string content with streaming api:

```
if ("data".equals(fieldname))
     String strData = getValueAsString(jp);
```

and

```
    private static String getValueAsString(JsonParser jp)
        throws com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException, IOException {
    JsonToken token = jp.getCurrentToken();
    int counter = 0;

    long startIndex = jp.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();
    long endIndex = 0;

    if (token == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
        // JsonLocation location = jp.getCurrentLocation();
        // startIndex = location.getCharOffset();
        // System.out.println("，location=" + new Gson().toJson(location) +
        // ", start=" + startIndex);

        counter++;
        while (counter > 0) {
            token = jp.nextToken();
            if (token == JsonToken.START_OBJECT)
                counter++;
            if (token == JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                counter--;
                endIndex = jp.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();
            }
        }

        return data.substring((int) startIndex - 1, (int) endIndex);

    } else if (token == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
        counter++;
        while (counter > 0) {
            token = jp.nextToken();
            if (token == JsonToken.START_ARRAY)
                counter++;
            if (token == JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                counter--;
                endIndex = jp.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();
            }
        }
        return data.substring((int) startIndex - 1, (int) endIndex);

    } else {
        return jp.getText();
    }
}
```

it works when data source is String. for none string source such as file, using `JsonLocation.getByteOffset()` instead of `JsonLocation.getCharOffset()`